# Bigger font in IE - fine in FF

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On this page: http://catonthecouchproductions.com/fish/fishing-trips.html in IE the font is much larger and is cutting off the page. I have a simple:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="all">.borderitem {
border-style:solid;
}
p.trip-includes-text,ul li{
font-size:10px;
}
p.about-text{
font-size:11px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If conditional to change the font but I cant get it to change. As well as the includes box on the bottom left, it is being cut out.

Comment: I also find this to be the case, that the fonts are generally bigger in IE.  As with other IE-related time-wasting, there is the small consolation, "at least it's not just me".

Answer (score 1):

It's not the font, it's the size of the box that contains the text that IE has changed. I've had this before and making the box bigger (with margins or padding) makes it work ok.

Comment: But the font looks much larger than in FF, how is it not the font? If so thats strange, haha.

Comment: Hmm ok, which version of IE are you using? I compared both FF and IE 7 and the font looked the same size to me, but I did see the text going outside of the box, hence I thought of the issue I had.